# Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String

Tags: java

```
public String getMessage (int numEggs) {

    int a = numEggs/12;
    int b = numEggs%12;

    if ( numEggs < 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid number");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your number of eggs is "+ a +" dozen(s) and "+ b+".");
        return;
    }
}
```

So I keep getting `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String` when I try to put something in the return; what's wrong with the code? I have to use `getMessage (int numEggs)` as it is part of the question I was given.

Comment: I think the intention of the exercise is to have you _return_ the message, not print it to the screen like you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String` but the error is: `This method must return a result of type String`

You're missing return statement in your method:

```
public String getMessage(int numEggs) {

    int a = numEggs / 12;
    int b = numEggs % 12;

    if (numEggs < 0) {
        return "Invalid number";
    } else {
        return "Your number of eggs is " + a + " dozen(s) and "
                + b + ".";          
    }
}
```

Even I change the `getMessage` return type to `void` it doesn't give me `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String`

```
public void getMessage(int numEggs) {

    int a = numEggs / 12;
    int b = numEggs % 12;

    if (numEggs < 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid number");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your number of eggs is " + a + " dozen(s) and "
                + b + ".");
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> cannot convert from int to String" when i try to put something in the return,

The method expects you to return a String. So you can't do:

```
return 1; //ie 1, does not get automatically converted to "1"
```

But you can do:

```
return "I'm a String";
```

Comment: so does that mean instead of using the System.out.println i should use return?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to return a string?
if you just desire to print, simply make the return type void and remove the "return" at the bottom.

Comment: There is no problem with return statement if you change the return type to `void`

Comment: @IswantoSan the return statement is unnecessary, removing it would just improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a String:

public String getMessage (int numEggs) {

```
int a = numEggs/12;
int b = numEggs%12;
String strReturn = "";

if ( numEggs < 0) {
    strReturn = "Invalid number";
} else {
    strReturn = "Your number of eggs is "+ a +" dozen(s) and "+ b+".";

}
return strReturn;
```

}

If you want to print it in the consolse then

public void getMessage (int numEggs) {

```
int a = numEggs/12;
int b = numEggs%12;

if ( numEggs < 0) {
    System.out.println("Invalid number");
} else {
    System.out.println("Your number of eggs is "+ a +" dozen(s) and "+ b+".");
}
```

}